# Python Pandas: groupby one column, aggregate in only one other column, but take corresponding data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have seen a number of other related SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217014/pandas-groupby-aggregate-only-one-column) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby), but they do not seem to be exactly what I want. Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['patient', 'parent csn', 'child csn', 'days'])
df.loc[0] = [0, 0, 10, 5]
df.loc[1] = [0, 0, 11, 3]
df.loc[2] = [0, 1, 12, 6]
df.loc[3] = [0, 1, 13, 4]
df.loc[4] = [1, 2, 20, 4]
df
Out[9]: 
  patient parent csn child csn days
0       0          0        10    5
1       0          0        11    3
2       0          1        12    6
3       0          1        13    4
4       1          2        20    4
```

Now what I want to do is something like this:

```
grp_df = df.groupby(['parent csn']).min()
```

The problem is that the result computes the min across **all** columns (that aren't `parent csn`), and that produces:

```
grp_df
            patient  child csn  days
parent csn                          
0                 0         10     3
1                 0         12     4
2                 1         20     4
```

You can see that for the first row, the `days` number and the `child csn` number are no longer on the same row, like they were before grouping. Here's the output I want:

```
grp_df
            patient  child csn  days
parent csn                          
0                 0         11     3
1                 0         13     4
2                 1         20     4
```

How can I get that? I have code that iterates through the dataframe, and I think it will work, but it is slow as all get-out, even with Cython. I feel like this should be obvious, but I am not finding it so.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751229/pandas-sum-by-groupby-but-exclude-certain-columns) question as well, but putting the `child csn` in the groupby list will not work, because `child csn` varies as `days`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327397/pandas-multiindex-groupby-aggregate-column-with-value-from-another-column) question seems more likely, but I'm not finding the solutions very intuitive.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51074911/pandas-get-minimum-of-one-column-in-group-when-groupby-another) question also seems likely, but again, the answers aren't very intuitive, plus I do want only one row for each `parent csn`.

One other detail: the row containing the minimum `days` value might not be unique. In that case, I just want one row - I don't care which.

Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by using `.idxmin()` instead of `.min()` to get the index (row identifier) where "days" is at it minimum for each group:

data creation:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[0, 0, 10, 5],
        [0, 0, 11, 3],
        [0, 1, 12, 6],
        [0, 1, 13, 4],
        [1, 2, 20, 4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['patient', 'parent csn', 'child csn', 'days'])

print(df)
   patient  parent csn  child csn  days
0        0           0         10     5
1        0           0         11     3
2        0           1         12     6
3        0           1         13     4
4        1           2         20     4
```

```
day_minimum_row_indices = df.groupby("parent csn")["days"].idxmin()

print(day_minimum_row_indices)
parent csn
0    1
1    3
2    4
Name: days, dtype: int64
```

From this you can see that the group parent csn 0 had a minimum number of days at row 1. Looking back to our original dataframe, we can see that row 1 had days == 3 and is infact the location of the minimum days for parent csn == 0. Parent csn == 1 had a minimum days at row 3, so on and so forth.

We can use the row indices to subset back into our original dataframe:

```
new_df = df.loc[day_minimum_row_indices]

print(new_df)
   patient  parent csn  child csn  days
1        0           0         11     3
3        0           1         13     4
4        1           2         20     4
```

---

Edit (tldr):

```
df.loc[df.groupby("parent csn")["days"].idxmin()]
```

Answer (score 4):

As your desired ouput, you need `sort_values` and groupby `first`

```
df_final = (df.sort_values(['parent csn', 'patient', 'days', 'parent csn'])
              .groupby('parent csn').first())

Out[813]:
            patient  child csn  days
parent csn
0                 0         11     3
1                 0         13     4
2                 1         20     4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by the dataframe for the rows you need *using groupby to create the filter* rather than just using .groupby:

```
s = df.groupby('parent csn')['days'].transform('min') == df['days']
df = df[s]
df

Out[1]: 
   patient  parent csn  child csn  days
1        0           0         11     3
3        0           1         13     4
4        1           2         20     4
```

For example, this is is how it would look like if I put `s` in my dataframe. Then you just filter for the `True` rows which are the ones where minimum days per group are equal to that row.

```
Out[2]: 
   patient  parent csn  child csn  days      s
0        0           0         10     5  False
1        0           0         11     3   True
2        0           1         12     6  False
3        0           1         13     4   True
4        1           2         20     4   True
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I can't explain your dataframe has columns of type `object`. This solution only works with numerical columns

```
df.days = df.days.astype(int)
df.iloc[df.groupby('parent csn').days.idxmin()]
```

Out:

```
  patient parent csn child csn  days
1       0          0        11     3
3       0          1        13     4
4       1          2        20     4
```

Comment: It's because the dataframe began empty. Pandas doesnt assume the datatype of columns with nothing in it so it leaves them as "object" dtypes (which is the most flexible). Then when you "fill" the columns in via `.loc` they retain their "object" dtype. On an unrelated note, you should also use `.loc` for your answer because `idxmin()` returns the corresponding index associated with the minimum- so this answer would fail if the index were ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

Comment: @AdrianKeister - Please consider to accept [@CameronRiddell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64472611/14277722) instead. It's the same idea but more informative for other readers and was posted before my solution.

Comment: Very well, if you wish. I can see they're more-or-less the same. Your answer is nice because the code's all in one place, though.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I appreciate it! I've added a "tldr" to my answer.